# Fastest and Safest way to increase Swap Space on Scientific Linux

Tags: memory, swap, scientific-linux, out-of-memory

**Memory Swap Ratio Company System**

Today, a monitoring system indicated that one of the systems in the company has run out of memory. Executing `htop` on this system indicated that the `Memory` was nearly full `(~8GB)` even as the `Swap Space (~0.5GB)`.

Stopping some of the services decreased the `Memory` use, but the `Swap Space` remained fully allocated.

According to [this documentation](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s1-swap-what-is.html) it seems that the `Swap Space` of this Company's system does not match the recommended space:

`S = M < 2 ? M * 2 : M + 2`

**Default Swap Space Test System**

Executing `htop` on a test system results in:

[image]

which means a ratio of `~1:1 (1877/1799)`.

**Subquestion:** Why does the default `Swap Memory Space Ratio` not equal `2:1`?

---

**Clear and Increase Swap Space on a running system**

*Increase Swap Space*

[This documentation](http://www.linux.com/news/software/applications/8208-all-about-linux-swap-space) indicates that several commands should be executed in order to increase the Swap Space. Are all these commands really required?

*Clear Swap Space*

According to [this documentation](http://www.linuxnetadmin.com/2008/11/clear-swap-space-in-linux.html) the Swap Space could be cleared by executing:

`swapoff -a && swapon -a`

*Safely increase Swap Space*

[This documentation](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/442430-increase-your-available-swap-space-with-a-swap-file) recommends to create a backup before increasing the Swap Space, but it does not indicate the possible impact. As this concerns a production system it is important to know if it is safe to increase the Swap Space on the system while it runs or e.g. should a new system be created and the date subsequently be moved?

---

**Question:**

What is the fastest and safest way to increase the Swap Space on Scientific Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a LVM, you can allocate/create a new Logical Volume a format it as a swap space.

```
lvcreate -n swap2 -L 2G VG_NAME
mkswap /dev/VG_NAME/swap2
swapon -a
```

e.g the above will create a 2G LogicalVolume partition on VolumeGroup named `VG_NAME`, then format the LV as swap, and activated it.